# How to get HDD serial number

Tags: c#, .net

May be the title is duplicate. I am getting HDD of the laptop serial number successfully when no USB devices are connected. But when any USB is connected, the code gets the serial number of connected device. I only want the serial number of HDD of laptop or desktop even though USBs are connected.

Below is the code.

```
using System.Management;

namespace SystemInfo
{
    public class Info1
    {
        public static String GetHDDSerialNo()
        {
            ManagementClass mangnmt = new ManagementClass("Win32_LogicalDisk");
            ManagementObjectCollection mcol = mangnmt.GetInstances();
            string result = "";

            foreach (ManagementObject strt in mcol)
            {
                result += Convert.ToString(strt["VolumeSerialNumber"]);
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean a USB-HDD with "when any USB is connected" or really ANY USB device?

Comment: any USB device. even Internet USB Dongle.

Comment: What if there are multiple hard disks? Or there is no hard disk? Then what do you want to get?

Comment: I think you did not get the point. It's not the matter of how many hard disks you have. The question is about getting serial number of the pc's hard disk. read the question, what I said is the code gives me serial number of connected device, not the hdd's serial number.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 ManagementObjectSearcher theSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE InterfaceType='USB'");
        foreach (ManagementObject currentObject in theSearcher.Get())
        {
            ManagementObject theSerialNumberObjectQuery = new ManagementObject("Win32_PhysicalMedia.Tag='" + currentObject["DeviceID"] + "'");
            MessageBox.Show(theSerialNumberObjectQuery["SerialNumber"].ToString());
        }
```

Comment: It shows nothing. One more thing, I want to get the serial number of HDD of laptop or desktop, not the devices connected to them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WMI `Win32_DiskDrive`, filter on `MediaType` containing "fixed" and get the `SerialNumber`

Something like :

```
public static String GetHDDSerialNo()
{
    ManagementClass mangnmt = new ManagementClass("Win32_DiskDrive");
    ManagementObjectCollection mcol = mangnmt.GetInstances();
    string result = "";

    foreach (ManagementObject strt in mcol)
    {
        if (Convert.ToString(strt["MediaType"]).ToUpper().Contains("FIXED"))
        {
            result += Convert.ToString(strt["SerialNumber"]);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Media type can contain "External", "Removable", "fixed". Exact string depends on OS. On Seven and XP, that `String` can be different. That's why we use `Contains`.

[little reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394132%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)